# How to resign first responder if UITextField is programmatically created inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I’ve created a custom `tableViewCell` that contain just a `textField` for data entry, like in a form. How would I both move to the next `cell/textField` in the form when the user taps Done and ultimately resign the keyboard when the form is done?

update of problem:

I've created a separate file with the class for my custom `tableViewCell`. That cell contain just a `textfield` that's constrained to fit the whole cell. My current solution is to assign each cell as a `textField` delegate and resign first responder on each cell.

On my `tableViewController`, I'm dequeuing said custom cell 4 times for the simple form. But I'm not sure how to access the `textField` in the `tableViewCell` file for things like jumping to the next `textField` when the user taps Done or checking that all fields have valid entry to save the information.

Comment: there's a function for UIView to end all editing. endEditing(force: Bool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced same problem. So to encounter this i selected the option in Attribute Inspecter of tableView - **Keyboard > Dismiss on Drag**

(This will resign the textfield when you scroll the table view)

OR

You can use the tap gesture on table view/tableview cells to resign responder.

Answer (score 0):

A very short version of how I would approach what you're trying to do is:

1. Store an array of the `UITextField` currently displayed in the cells.
2. Append a text field to the array in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
3. Remove a text field in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
4. Keep a reference to the `UITextField` the user interacts with (via `UITextFieldDelegate`)
5. Whenever the user pressed 'Done' call `resignFirstResponder()` on the UITextField set at step 4
6. Search for the index of the dismissed text field in the array of visible `UITextField`.
7. Increment the index and call `beginFirstResponder()` on the UITextField at this index.